# How to whitelist (Production) my android app in Uber?

Tags: android, uber-api

I am using uber api in my android app. Firstly I am getting invalid scope in uber after authentication to my account, but later I find out the solution for this.

This is working when I add an account(email) as admin in developers in uber dash board.

But I want to make this available to all other user who uses my app. So for this I have to **request for whitelisting in Uber Dev Dashboard** as suggest in help section.

But I am not getting any option for that. Can any body have solution for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This is working when I add an account(email) as admin in developers in uber dash board."  - Yes, Uber allows limited access to privileged scopes, for the user and up to 5 users added in the developer dashboard.

For whitelisting, here are the steps to Request Full Access:

1. Sign In to the Developer Dashboard
2. Click the Authorization tab
3. Click Request Full Access next to the privileged scope
4. Provide as much information about your app as possible
5. Submit the request

https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/scopes

For posts, questions like this in the future that do not deal with programming but are instead specific to Uber's platform, please post on the Uber developer community forum. Thanks.